# How to install all the dependencies using npm in node 6.10.1

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

Issue:
If I run the following command

```
npm install
```

Only the packages mentioned inside the "dependencies" section in the package.json file is installed. Those in the "devDependencies" are not being installed. For installing the "devDependencies" I need to run the following command:

```
npm install --only=dev
```

My question, is is there a way that I can install both by a single command (I know I can do it by defining an npm custom script,but I don't prefer that solution).

Note: My node version is 6.10.1
This issue started to occur after my up-gradation to 6.10.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually `npm install` command install dev dependencies as well, the occasion that it does not happen is when npm config production value is set to true. If this value is true, it will skip over the dev dependencies. To fix this issue,

Run the following

```
npm config get production
```

To set it to false

```
 npm config set -g production false
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `npm --production=false install`